# ng-route to read the link and locate the specific controller with the same name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ng-click` and `ng-view` to route my `div id= "listings"` to show different types of mobile listings such as `iphone 4`, `iphone 5`, `nexus 4`, `nexus 5`, `nexus 6`, `lg g3` etc.

Here is my [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0h2uXht7zJo0MSAzT4RZ?p=preview).

```
<div ng-repeat = 'breakdown in selected.breakdowns' ng-href = '#{{breakdown}}'>

  {{breakdown}}

</div>
```

In my routeProvider:

```
.when('/', {
    controller  : 'home-ctrl',
})
.when('/nexus_4, {
    controller : 'nexus_4-ctrl',
    templateUrl : 'listings.html',
})
```

and so on. But this seems tedious. Rather than doing it for each individually, is there a way for the app to read the URL, for example `mywebsite.com/nexus_5`, then search for a controller file named `nexus_5-ctrl`?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it necessary to use different controllers for each phone? I think you can make use of routeParam in your controller to load values accordingly. 

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: @RaghuVenmarathoor This is just an example, but basically my goal is to have the listings page that would show all the chosen phones for sale around my area. I dont know much about Angular, but do you think I can make use of routeParam for this? There will be calling of Map API and some firebase stuff.

Answer (score 1):

According to me their is no any way to bind dynamic controller to any route. You have to create route for each possible state. yes you can load your controllers file dynamically or say on Demand by using [Lazy load](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad). I used the same in my projects and its working fine with me.

Here is snippet of my code how I am doing this.

```
 resolve : {
        loadSummerNote:function($ocLazyLoad){
             return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                   name:"summernote",   
                   files: ['/bower_components/summernote/dist/summernote.css','/bower_components/angular-summernote/dist/angular-summernote.min.js','/bower_components/summernote/dist/summernote.min.js']
                })
        },
      loadUploadFile:function($ocLazyLoad,loadSummerNote){
           return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                  name: 'ngFileUpload',
                  files: ['/bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js','/bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js']
              })
      }, 
      currentDomain : function (Domain, $stateParams,loadUploadFile,User){
        return Domain.getDomain();
      }
     },
     controller : "domain"
```

Load all required files in resolve block so all dependency must be loaded before loading controller.

2. One more solution for this is to use angular [UI-ROUTER](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) . ui- router support multiple view in a single state. So no need to create state for every possible case. just create view for theme.

Comment: There is controllerProvider in ui-router which will help to inject dynamic controller in your state. Looks like a good feature to have.